# Can't save memo tagged value of a wireframe table element in Enterprise Architect

Tags: enterprise-architect

I'd like to reorder the columns of a wireframe table element using taged value editor in EA (v12). I can edit it's content and if I close and reopen the taged value note window it looks like all the changes are saved, but if I press OK on table properties window I lost all of them.

[image]

I noticed a little star beside  tag that I tried to edit. Does that means that it is not allowed to change (save) its content? Or is there any other way to reorder the columns of a table element?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open the Wireframe tab right below:

[image]

This allows editing the table. The memo tag is locked since there's MDG magic working inside this element.

As a bypass (I don't believe that Sparx will alter this even on request) you can use a little script to assist you.

```
my $e = $rep->GetElementByGUID("{8BA764D9-E132-446e-9DDC-3F51D60E9B8C}");
my $t = $e->TaggedValues->GetAt(2);
$t->{Notes} =~s/Row/Roar/g;
$t->Update();
```

(Sorry for the Perl.) The 3rd tagged value contains the table description. Here I just changed the default text globally so it appears as

[image]

If the diagram is shown on the current diagram you need to either close/open it or issue a `Repository.ReloadDiagram (diagram.DiagramID)`.

Comment: Thank you, but there is no option to reorder columns. I mean if I want to insert column3 before column0 in I have to delete all the columns and start it over.

Comment: Yes. This is EA. What you expect? They have tons of those brain dead gimmicks >:-(  Send a bug report and wait a couple of years. I'll have a look tomorrow how to get a work around for thus,

Comment: As promised I described a work around. Feel free to send a feature request to Sparx. But don't hold your breath.

Comment: Wow! That was fast and pro. Thank your very much, I really apreciate it.  Have no experience with perl script integration in EA, but I will manage it somehow.

Comment: Ah, Perl is something I just use (for various reasons). EA has build-in VB and J(ava)Script (never get those differences). And you can run any external scripting (like me) through the API.